Tidyeval and rlang within a nested tibble
I've attached a simple reproducible example below.
I'm currently working within a nested tibble with dynamic column names. I'm using the purrr::map() function to pass the column data into an anonymous function. Within the anonymous function I'm using the rlang::data_sym() function to convert the first and second column names into a symbol. I'm trying to create a new column using the dplyr::mutate() function within the anonymous function to calculate the sum of var1 and var2 by unquoting them using the !! operator.
The goal is to create a new column total that is the sum of the unquoted var1 and var2
iris |>
  group_nest(Species) |>
  mutate(data = map(data, \(x) {
    col_names <- names(x)
    
    var1 <- data_sym(col_names[[1]])
    var2 <- data_sym(col_names[[2]])
    
    x |> 
      mutate(
        total = !!var1 + !!var2
      )
    
  }))

The error is the following:

Error: object 'var1' not found

I'm trying to understand why this does not work, and what are potential alternatives. Why is var1 not found?

var1 is created, but not evaluated inside the mutate. It works with eval().
!! is used to unquote a single argument in a function call. I understand this to mean !! can only be used in a quoted context and takes a single expression. is.expression() below returns FALSE.
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

iris |>
  group_nest(Species) |>
  mutate(data = map(data, \(x) {
    
    col_names <- names(x)
    
    var1 <- data_sym(col_names[[1]])
    var2 <- data_sym(col_names[[2]])
    print(is.expression(var1)) # result = FALSE

    x |>
      mutate(
        total = eval(var1) + eval(var2)
      )
    
  })) |> 
  unnest(data)
#> [1] FALSE
#> [1] FALSE
#> [1] FALSE
#> # A tibble: 150 × 6
#>    Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width total
#>    <fct>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 setosa           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2   8.6
#>  2 setosa           4.9         3            1.4         0.2   7.9
#>  3 setosa           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2   7.9
#>  4 setosa           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2   7.7
#>  5 setosa           5           3.6          1.4         0.2   8.6
#>  6 setosa           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4   9.3
#>  7 setosa           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3   8  
#>  8 setosa           5           3.4          1.5         0.2   8.4
#>  9 setosa           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2   7.3
#> 10 setosa           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1   8  
#> # ℹ 140 more rows

Created on 2024-04-24 with reprex v2.1.0

There does seem to be some kind of inconsistency going on. If I try a simplier case of
iris |>
  group_nest(Species) |>
  mutate(data = map(data, \(x) {
    colsym <- sym("Sepal.Length")
    x %>% mutate(newcol=!!colsym)
  }))

Or looking at the traceback, the error seems to be triggered by code like this
quo(\(x) {bee <- rlang::sym("a"); mutate(x, a=!!bee)})

So it seems to be trying to resolve the !! too eagerly.
But If I move the anonymous function outside the map, it works
helper <- \(x) {
  colsym <- sym("Sepal.Length")
  x %>% mutate(newcol=!!colsym)
}

iris |>
  group_nest(Species) |>
  mutate(data = map(data, helper))

So you could move your function definition outside the map and it might work.
This problem seems very related to this github issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/7016
